# Web Api - Authorization on a per-user basis using annotations

Tags: authorization, asp.net-web-api, roles, custom-attributes

is it possible to achieve a user-based authorization procedure using an annotation?
I'm building a REST Api and I would like users to only be access items that belong to them. This is achieved by looking at the transmitted AccessToken which contains a user's id, from where I can tell if a user is authorized to view the requested content or not.

In order to avoid a static authorization procedure inside each Controller.Method() I would very much like to just use an AuthorizationAttribute like this:

```
[RestrictAccess(Access.ADMIN, Access.OWNER)]
public SensitiveData GetSensitiveData(Guid userId) {

     return Repository.GetSensitiveData(userId);

}
```

For example, this method should only be allowed to be called by all users with AccessRole ADMIN and the OWNER of the requested item.

Essentially I am looking for a way to use the Controller's parameters at run time inside my AuthorizationAttribute. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
public class Restriction : ActionFilterAttribute {

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {

        // holds a dictionary of arguments passed to annotated Controller.
        var arguments = actionContext.ActionArguments; 

        base.OnActionExecuting

    }

}
```

Comment: Does this work for you?  My ActionArguments isn't getting a copy of the parameters I'm passing into the Controller....